# Apple Mail.app - Delete all mails and account settings?

Tags: apple-mail

I have recently moved all my data and settings to a new Mac, including my Mailboxes and Apple Mail.app settings. Now I want to keep my old MacBook as a secondary device and keep the user profile as well, but I want to make absolutely sure that the old Mail settings do not kick in and retrieve some mail from the mail servers. I don't want to use Mail on this system any more. How do I reliably kill all data and settings of Mail.app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I deleted

- `~/Library/Mail` which seems to contain the mailbox contents and general settings
- `~/Library/Mail Downloads` with the files extracted from Mails over the time
- `~/Library/Application Support/Mail` which seemed to contain at least some of the mail account settings

After cutting all network connections, I started Mail and was greeted with the default Welcome wizard - so I assume that this was the solution.